# How to load files in parallel with rx-java?

Tags: android, rx-java

I am looking for a proper way to download multiple (image) files in parallel with rxjava.
After all files have completed downloading, the subscriber should be notified.

However the only way to do this I found is like this:

```
retrieveSlidesPlistObservable()

        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

        .flatMap(slidesPlist -> {

            final ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 4, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

            String[] imagesUrls = slidesPlist.getImageUrls();
            Observable<? extends String>[] imgDownloadObservables = new Observable[imagesUrls.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < imagesUrls.length; i++) {
                imgDownloadObservables[i] = Observable.from(executor.submit(new DownloadResourceCallable(imagesUrls[i])));
            }

            return Observable.merge(imgDownloadObservables);
        })

        .subscribe(
                onNext -> {
                    log("onNext:" + onNext);
                },
                throwable -> {
                    log("onError");
                },
                () -> {
                    log("onComplete");
                }
        );

...

private static final class DownloadResourceCallable implements Callable<String> {
    private final String mUrl;

    public DownloadResourceCallable(final String url) {
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        log("downloading " + mUrl + "...");
        // simulate fetching data from remote service
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return "success " + mUrl;
    }
}
```

But filling an `Observable<? extends String>[]` array like that just doesn’t feel right.

1. Is there a better -more rx-ish way to achieve this?
2. How would one publish the current progress like in an android AsyncTask with onProgressUpdate() ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this on what I understand of your use case:

Create a `Scheduler` based on your executor (or just use a standard one like `Schedulers.io()`:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(executor);
```

Instead of using `Future` and `Callable` you could just do this (I'm not sure you what your constraints are):

```
retrieveSlidesPlistObservable()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap(slidesPlist -> 
        Observable.from(slidesPlist.getImageUrls())
    .flatMap(url ->
        Observable.from(url)
            .doOnNext(url -> downloadUrl())
            .subscribeOn(scheduler))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(...)
```

You could update progress at meaningful places in the `downloadUrl()` method  (assuming `downloadUrl()` doesn't launch async stuff itself).

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for your answer. With your suggested code the downloads run on the specified scheduler/thread but one after another and not in parallel.

Comment: Try replacing scheduler with Schedulers.io() and test again

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference. All sources are downloaded one after another.

Comment: So this is definitely the pattern to use (flatMap(  .subscribeOn())) for parallel processing. Should the observeOn be just before the .subscribe()? By the way the getImageUrls results will be downloaded one after the other. But each of the sets of images will be processed in parallel. I'll adjust the answer to give you the behaviour you seem to be seeking.